# Mac OSX Homebrew r-app cask no longer exists

Tags: macos, homebrew

r-app has disappeared from homebrew, you can no longer `brew cask install r-app`

are there any alternatives or ways to install the cask now? I would prefer to install the r-app cask if possible.

Comment: @RajeshS why is this helpful?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out all the cask does is install the latest R .pkg file, so doing that manually achieves the same result.

Side note: There was a recent R update to 3.5.3 which might be the reason why the cask is removed for the time being.

Comment: Installing only the GUI from package won't work though. The whole package needs to be installed, including R binaries. Which kind of renders the entire homebrew install of R useless. It seems like R needs to be installed via the official package now, for anyone using the GUI.

Answer (score 0):

The cask was renamed to just `r` rather than `r-app`

```
`brew cask install r`
```